# IMPORTRANGE and SUM of column show 0

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a workbook that is importing data from another workbook.
It is pulling all the data in just fine using

```
=query(importrange("1iY25u07bWHgEYywGmO3S9QTTQsuHOANQBysL9zg7CGI","DATA!A2:AD5000"), "select * where Col30 <> '' and Col30 = 'District Manny'")
```

The issue is that in Column AB I have Payments displaying and they show up fine in the sheet.  But when I make another sheet to show totals it just shows 0.

```
=SUM(filter(DATA!AB:AB,DATA!A:A=A16))
```

If I take out the SUM from above it shows all the values that match the criteria.  I want to sum those values not show all values.  The bizarre part is that in column AA I have similar values that work perfectly with the above formula.

The only difference is in the original sheet the AB column looks like this

```
=if(isblank(Z8)," ",Z8-AA8)
```

Am I missing something big here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a formatting issue caused by **`" "`** in `=IF(ISBLANK(Z8), " ", Z8-AA8)`

you can fix it directly there like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Z8), , Z8-AA8)
```

or use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM` like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(DATA!AB:AB, DATA!A:A=A16))
```